# Multi column table ios Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm new at Xamarin ios development. I want to create a table with 3 columns and grouped. I want to do something like this:

[image]

I want to do this in code. How can I do this? Can someone please explain it to me step by step.

Comment: I have tried tableview. But I couldn't manage to get the tableview working with multipule columns.

Comment: This could be defined in a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell which simply aligns data just like in the example you've provided. Although I would argue you would do it differently on iOS. Take a look at how Cells look in your Contacts app on your device.

Comment: I think you are right. I finally ended showing data differently. Just like you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this component:

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin-ios/datagrid

There are sorting, grouping and filtering functionality.